# What is the formula's are used to convert to meters/second?

Tags: fractions

What are the formula's to convert the following per hour intervals into meters per second (using meters/s from light speed):

- Kilometer
- Mile (US)
- Mile (Nautical)
- Feet

The result should be decimal form of each interval with no E+/- in the float section.

**Note: Please edit tags as I couldn't find any relating to conversion or for formulas. I am actually surprised there were no other applicable tags aside from `fractions` as this is a basic mathematical principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to convert $5$ kilometers/hour to something in meters/s. $5$ km/hr is written as

$$\frac{5\ \text{km}}{1\ \text{hr}}$$

First we will get this km/hr to m/hr by using $1000$ m = $1$ km.

$$\frac{5\ \text{km}}{1\ \text{hr}}\times\frac{1000\ \text{m}}{1\ \text{km}}$$

This works because mutiplying by $1000$m/$1$km is the same as multiplying by $1$.

$$\require{cancel}\frac{5\ \cancel{\text{km}}}{1\ \text{hr}}\times\frac{1000\ \text{m}}{1\ \cancel{\text{km}}} = \frac{5000\ \text{m}}{1\ \text{hr}}$$

Now we go from m/hr to m/s using $1$hr = $60$min and $1$min = $60$s

$$\frac{5000\ \text{m}}{1\ \cancel{\text{hr}}}\times\frac{1\ \cancel{\text{hr}}}{60\ \cancel{\text{min}}}\times\frac{1\ \cancel{\text{min}}}{60\ \text{s}} = \frac{5000\ \text{m}}{60\times60\ \text{s}}$$
$$\begin{align}&=\frac{25}{18}\text{m/s}\\\\&\approx1.3889\text{m/s}\end{align}$$

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding the notation (not that it's wrong ... just reading formulas I am used to them in algebraic form -- aka   `(4^2)/((10^7) * 40)` )

Comment: I hope this edit helps

Comment: I think so ---- `m = km * 1000`   `mps = (m / 3600)`  (mps = meteres per sec). Basically, i need to convert the measurement first, then divide the result by 3600 seconds for `meters per second`.  (also, looking at the edit of your answer -- thats crazy ... do you have a program to assist with writing all that ? )

Comment: Yes, you're pretty much doing two conversions at once. One for km to m, and one for hr to s. And you learn to think in TeX eventually.